# How to deal with encoding content-type formats in an API?

Tags: api, content-type, api-design, cbor

I am designing an API that supports the following content-types: JSON, Protobuf and XML.

When I want to send plain JSON I would use: `application/json`. Would this be valid too: `cbor/json` if I want to sent through JSON encoded as CBOR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the mime type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) and [RFC 7049](http://www.iana.org/go/rfc7049), use application/cbor.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I might misunderstand something here. I can convert JSON into CBOR, I can also convert XML into CBOR. Would the 'same' XML and JSON end up as the same or different CBOR?